# ignore mismatched column types with to_csv and dask

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dask

I am trying to export a dataframe using dask with the `dask.dataframe.to_csv(datframe_name, file etc..)` command that was listed in the Dask manual: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv

I'm using `dask` because the original csv file was very large (20Gb) and it was very slow to use pandas to read the file.

However, everything I try to export the dataframe I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.

+----------+--------+----------+
| Column   | Found  | Expected |
+----------+--------+----------+
| DeviceID | object | int64    |
| Lat      | object | float64  |
| Long     | object | float64  |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

It is strange that the dataframe is finding the columns as objects, when their `dtypes` are integer and float.

Is there a way to ignore reading the columns' types and just export the dataframe as is?

Comment: This might happen when you have mixed types within the columns. Try clean and check the data before write them back to file.

Comment: @FabioLamanna, would you recommend I use `.astype()` command?  I did a `df.dtypes` check before exporting the dataframe, and the columns were of the same type as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that when reading your data from the original CSV files Dask dataframe found that your data actually wasn't numeric as it originally guessed.  A common cause for this is that you have a few rows of your data that actually aren't numeric in some way.  Perhaps you have a custom NA value or some of the rows of your data are mismatched in some way.